# выпадающий список WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

(сайт на WordPress) Подскажите как реализовать выпадающий список при нажатии на кнопку (список в две колонки фото - инфо ) в Google не нашел подходящего решения. Благодарен любым советам.

Comment: Задавать вопрос второй раз не имеет смысла и противоречит правилам сообщества. Видимо, на ваш вопрос нет ответа, раз промолчали. Лично мне такие узкоспециализированные плагины неизвестны.Наверное, следует обратиться на фриланс.

Comment: понял, спасибо, буду что-то думать

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, всё достаточно просто.
Делаем `button id="show-info onclick="showInfo()""` 
И блок вроде  `div id="info"`  в котором делаем вывод нужной инфы в две колонки. Изначально это блок в css будет иметь свойство `display:none;`
Ну а потом с помощью jQuery или JS делаем вывод, просто меняем атрибут `display` на `block`
Что-то вроде

```
function showInfo() {
    var info = document.getElementById('info');
    info.setAttribute("display" , "block")
};
```

Как-то так должно сработать)